# Python development headers on Mac OS X El Capitan for compiling Freeling API

Tags: python, xcode, macos, python-3.x

I am trying to install Freeling in Mac Os X El Capitan v. 10.11. I want to work with Freeling as a module for Python 3.5. I have to say in advance that this is my first serious contact with Mac...

I have installed Freeling and it runs well in the command line. My problem comes when I try to generate the module for Python.

Following the instructions, I have prepared the makefile and I have issued 'make' in the command line for generating the module. But I got this problem:

> freeling_pythonAPI.cxx:171:11: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
>
> ## include < Python.h >
>
> ```
>      ^
> ```
>
> 1 error generated.
>   make: *** [_freeling.so] Error 1

In the documentation, it is prescribed the following:

> 1.- Make sure python development headers are installed

I suppose that the solution will come from this way.
The Python Developers Guide (https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html) explains what to do for installing the python development headers on Mac OS X:

> How the command line tools are installed varies by OS X and Xcode release. In earlier releases, there may be a separate installer download. For OS X 10.7 and 10.8, there is an option in the Xcode app Preferences menu. For OS X 10.9 (Mavericks), run the following:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

So, I run this command, and I got this message:

```
$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

And here it comes my question. After having run the instruction for generating the Python API, I got the impression that headers were missing. However, if I try to install the headers, it seems to me that they are already installed. Is that xcode instruction valid for Capitan? Or maybe am I missing something?

Any received counsel will be very much appreciated.

Best, 
TomB

Comment: Is there no `python3-dev` package ? Also python2 is not python3 so you would need the headers installed separately

Comment: I have found python3-dev for Ubuntu, but I do not know how to get that 'tool' for MacOs. Do you have some idea?